# How to use vectors (of C++ STL) with WebAssembly

Tags: c++14, webassembly

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> ver;

int pushData(int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ver.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

I want to call pushData function from JS and push some data to vector "ver" and use it later.
please explain how to do that using WebAssembly.

Answer (score 1):

i'm do something like you.In my opinion, using STL in WASM is very difficult.

My solution is to create a simulate vector.Wasm only supports int32, int64, float32 and float64 and wasm's adderess is differnt from other process.So it is not feasible to import the library directly. You can call the library function through a proxy or conversion.Or you can write it by yourself.

In this case, `vector` can't be imported directly.You can create a class named `vector`,and implement the `push_back` function.

```
class vector{
public:
    bool push_back(int i){
       // do something
    }
    int& at(uint index){
       // do something
    }
private:
    int* int_ptr;
}
```

More details here
https://aransentin.github.io/cwasm/